# Added wrong default value in new field and now can't migrate

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I added a user foreign field in one of my models and made a migration. I was prompted to add a default value. The default value for user is suppose to be Int, representing the user_id. Instead of adding an Int, I added a string "username".

Now I'm stuck with:

```
return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'testuser'
```

I deleted all the objects associated with the model, and tried migrating, that didn't work, getting same error. (`Model.objects.all().delete()`)

I reverted to a previous migration, that didn't solve the problem, when I migrated, it got the same ValueError. (`./manage.py migrate app 0037_auto_20170330_0326`)

Lastly, I deleted my new foreign field, but that didn't solve the issue either.

What other options do I have in such a scenario?

My model is very simple:

```
class Chat(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User) #new field that was added
    message = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Comment: Does the username value or this user field still persist in the Chat table in database?

Comment: @AKS No it doesn't, which is why I'm confused. `>>> a = Chat.objects.all().count()
>>> a
0
>>> `

Comment: If you are already at migration 0036 then try these steps: (1) delete the migration 0037, (2) set `null=True` in the user field in Chat model, (3) Make migration and try migrating again.

Comment: @AKS I will give that a try and get back to you shortly. Thanks.

Comment: @AKS I deleted the migration the migration and it worked, thanks. Leave it as answer and I will accept. Note - It took me a little reading to figure out you delete migrations from your (appfolder -> migrations), rather than shell.

Comment: Glad that the suggestion worked. I have added my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are already at migration 0036, try following steps:

1. Delete the migration `0037_auto_20170330_0326`. It will be present at the following location:

   ```
   appfolder -> migrations -> 0037_auto_20170330_0326.py
   ```
2. Set `null=True` in `user` field in `Chat` model:

   ```
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
   ```
3. Migrate again!